# Problem with WCF Ria Services RequiresRole attribute

Tags: roles, wcf-ria-services

I have a User class that implemented the IUser interface and is used in the AuthenticationService of my WCF RIA app.

Whenever I apply the RequiresRole attribute to one of my operations I get Access to the operation is denied error even though WebContext.User.IsInRole("Managers") on the client side returns true.

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `WebContext.User.IsInRole` returns true because the `IUser` has a property `Roles`.

This property is set with the user's roles by the server at authentication/user-load time.

The result is that while the client has no access or knowledge on the persistent storage / server entities etc. of the roles in the server, it still has the primitive info (role names) that was rather provided to him by the server.