# Having a problem with RequiresRole attribute on RIA Domain service

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694277/problem-with-wcf-ria-services-requiresrole-attribute).  I hope I can provide some more detail and context to get it answered.

So here's some context: I have a simple in-house silverlight (ver 4) app with WCF Ria services that I'm building for our small support team.  It uses authentication against a third-party vended database, but all other user information, e.g. FriendlyName and Roles (only 1 role per user) comes from our own database.  I'm trying to keep this simple and don't want to implement custom membership and role providers.

I have few domain service operations that I want to restrict to certain roles, so I tried using the `RequiresRole` attribute like so:

```
[RequiresRole("Admin", "HelpDesk", "Billing" )]
public RisStudyInfo GetStudyInfo(string accession) {
    return ris.GetStudyInfo(accession);
}
```

On the client side `WebContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")` returns true, but I always get access denied when calling the service.  The `RequiresAuthentication` attribute works as expected.

Below is the implementation of my `AuthenticationService`. The `User` class simply inherits from `UserBase` and adds the FriendlyName property. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class AuthenticationService : AuthenticationBase<User> {

    UserDataService userData = new UserDataService();

    protected override bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password) {
        var auth = new DatabaseAuthenticator();
        return auth.Authenticate(userName, password);
    }

    protected override User GetAuthenticatedUser(IPrincipal principal) {
        User user = null;
        if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            user = new User();
            user.FriendlyName = userData.GetFriendlyName(principal.Identity.Name);
            user.Name = principal.Identity.Name;
            user.Roles = GetRolesFor(user.Name);
        }
        return user;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetRolesFor(string username) {

        IList<string> roles = new List<string>();

        string role = userData.GetRolesFor(username);
        if (role != null)
            roles.Add(role);

        return roles;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  At least 2 things wrong. First clue found [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/82592/193756.aspx). The second clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684005/custom-role-provider-not-working)

1.Turns out I really do need to write a custom role provider.  Only need to implement `GetRolesForUser` though.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) {
   return new string[] { _userService.GetRolesFor(username) };
}
```

2.Configure the custom role provider correctly in the web.config

```
<roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyProject.Web.Providers.MyRoleProvider, MyProject.Web"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one by using the local credential store to cache credentials. Whenever a local cred check fails a foreign check occurs and the cache is populated/updated. This was a trivial override of the ValidateUser method. It does mean that stale passwords continue to work until the updated password is used (it will fail locally, pass remotely and trigger an update).

This approach meant that internally everything worked as per an out of the box configuration with no need for any other mods (apart from removing the local create-a-user links).